# android paging3 pagingSource load not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gallery, android-paging-3

I am trying to create an image gallery get data using paging3 library.

Since there is no log in load of GalleryPagingSource, The load call does not work

So my guess is that the load function of pagingSource is not working.
Can you tell me which part is wrong?

data Pojo

```
data class GalleryPhoto(
        var id: Long? = null ,
        var filepath: String? = null,
        var uri: Uri? = null,
        var name: String? = null,
        var date: String? = null,
        var size: Int? = null
    )
```

Activity

```
val galleryPhotoRepository: GalleryPhotoRepository = GalleryPhotoRepository(GalleryModel(), applicationContext)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.getGalleryPagingImages(galleryPhotoRepository)
            viewModel.customGalleryPhotoList.cachedIn(this).collectLatest{
                Timber.d("Test Checked asdf $it")

                gridImagePickerAdapter.submitData(it) 
            }
        }
```

ViewModel

```
suspend fun getGalleryPagingImages(galleryPhotoRepository: GalleryPhotoRepository) {
        Timber.d("Test Checked asdf ~!")
        galleryPhotoRepository.getTodoContentItemsByPaging()
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            .collect {
                _customGalleryPhotoList.value = it
            }
    }
```

repository

```
class GalleryPhotoRepository(private val todoDao: GalleryModel, val context: Context) {

    fun getTodoContentItemsByPaging(): Flow<PagingData<ImagePojo.GalleryPhoto>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 50),
            pagingSourceFactory = { GalleryPagingSource(todoDao, context) }
        ).flow
    }
}
```

pagingSource

```
class GalleryPagingSource(
    private val dao: GalleryModel,
    val context : Context
): PagingSource<Int, ImagePojo.GalleryPhoto>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, ImagePojo.GalleryPhoto> {
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        return try {

            //items 에서 이미지 변환
            val items = dao.getAllPhotos(page, params.loadSize, context)

            Timber.d("Test CC ${items[0]}")
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = items,
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (items.isEmpty()) null else page + (params.loadSize / 10)
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.d("Test CC $e")
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, ImagePojo.GalleryPhoto>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }

}
```

GalleryModel

```
class GalleryModel {

    fun getAllPhotos(
        page: Int,
        loadSize: Int,
        context: Context
    ): MutableList<ImagePojo.GalleryPhoto> {
        val galleryPhotoList = mutableListOf<ImagePojo.GalleryPhoto>()
        // 외장 메모리에 있는 URI를 받도록 함
        val uriExternal: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        // 커서에 가져올 정보에 대해서 지정한다.
        val query: Cursor?
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, // 이름
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE, // 크기
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED, // 추가된 날짜
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID
        )
        val resolver = context.contentResolver

        var selection: String? = null
        var selectionArgs: Array<String>? = null

        query = resolver?.query(
            uriExternal,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            "${MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_ADDED} DESC"
        )

        query?.use { cursor ->
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID)
            val nameColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val filePathColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
            val sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE)
            val dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN)

            val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
            val filepath = cursor.getString(filePathColumn)
            val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
            val size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn)
            val date = cursor.getString(dateColumn)

            val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uriExternal, id)

            while (cursor.moveToNext() && cursor.position < loadSize * page) {
                if (cursor.position >= (page - 1) * loadSize) {
                    galleryPhotoList.add(
                        ImagePojo.GalleryPhoto(
                            id,
                            filepath = filepath,
                            uri = contentUri,
                            name = name,
                            date = date ?: "",
                            size = size
                        ))
                }
            }
        }
        for(i in 0 until galleryPhotoList.size) {
            Timber.d("Test CC ! ${galleryPhotoList[i].uri}")
        }


        return galleryPhotoList
    }
}
```